# Minimal \protected@edef example

Tags: macros, expansion

I recently came across `\protected@edef` in the/a LaTeX2e source. Can anyone give me a minimal or simple example, where I need this? I know this has to do with fragile commands/robustness, but I am looking for a concrete example.

Comment: Two great answers, hard to decide which one is the correct one. So I'll flip a coin to choose :) Thank you very much for the good explanation and example!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Joseph has given a very good explanation. To give you a complete tiny example just for testing to see a difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\firstsection}{\protect\centering First section}
\begin{document}
\edef\currentsection{\firstsection}
\section{\currentsection}
\end{document}
```

This fails to compile. We got `Undefined control sequence.` because `\edef` has thrown away the `\protect`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\firstsection}{\protect\centering First section}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\protected@edef\currentsection{\firstsection}
\makeatother
\section{\currentsection}
\end{document}
```

This compiles and works as expected, because `\protected@edef` keeps the effect of `\protect` within our macro.

Answer (score 28):

As you might guess, `\protected@edef` is a wrapper around the TeX `\edef` primitive. To understand what is going on, you need to understand the [difference between fragile and robust commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/): as this has been covered before here I'll assume you've read up on that difference!

What you may well know is that with fragile commands, it is often necessary to add `\protect` in front of them. When you define a macro with an optional argument, using `\DeclareRobustCommand` will set up an internal macro which includes this automatically.

I'm going to take as an example the `\cite` macro, which takes an optional argument and is defined using `\DeclareRobustCommand`. If you do

```
\show\cite
```

the result is

```
> \cite=macro:
->\protect \cite  .
```

Now, the `\protect` mechanism will not work inside a simple `\edef`. Try

```
\edef\test{\cite{stuff}}
```

with the `article` class and you get the rather cryptic

```
! Use of \\deftranslation doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b
```

Of course, you would not do this directly, but can imagine some user input being passed to an internal macro which needs to `\edef` the material. So how do you do the `\edef` while still allowing `\cite` to appear in the input? This is where `\protected@edef` comes in:

```
\makeatletter
\protected@edef\test{\cite{stuff}}
\show\test
```

gives the rather more reasonable

```
> \test=macro:
->\protect \cite  {stuff}.
```

Multiple `\protected@edef` calls will simply repeat this process: the `\cite` will not be expanded until the material is actually typeset (or you forgot to be safe and use `\edef`!).

How does this work? Well, `\protect` does not always have the same definition. Most of the time it is defined as `\relax`, so does nothing at all. However, `\protected@edef` changes the definition to

```
\noexpand\protect\noexpand
```

Inside an `\edef`, this will preserve the presence of `\protect` (to allow multiple `\protected@edef` calls), and will then prevent expansion of the next token: the macro we want to leave alone.

Similar considerations apply to `\protected@xdef` and `\protectd@write`, which have the same issues with expansion.

All of this is very clever, but you do have to remember to use `\protected@edef` and there are some circumstances where the protection fails. For that reason, the e-TeX extensions include the `\protected` primitive, which defines 'engine robust' macros. These never expand inside an `\edef`, without the need for any extra steps.

Comment: The 'normal' definition of `\protect` as `\relax` shows up nicely in Stefan's example.