# Macro for \AddToPictureShipoutFG when editing pdf with pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages

using `pdfpages` as a quick and dirty pdf annotation tool to fill in a pdf based form. I do this often and am really keen to try and stick to a linux environment.

There are a lot of entries so I'd like to use a macro to summarize the code

`\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\put(x_coord,y_coord){content}}` command with a macro. I've tried lots of variants on the \def below but keep getting errors. Any thoughts very appreciated. (including any other routes to take with this)

An MWE looks a little like the following with `somepdf` in the `\includepdf` command replaced by the pdf form in question.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{grffile} 
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\def\pd(#1,#2,#3){\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\put(#1,#2)\expandafter{#3}}}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\put(35,555){\large X}}
\pd(150,150,{Rhubarb and crumble})
\includepdf[pages=1-1]{"/home/me/somepdf"}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the `\expandafter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current definition of `\pd` includes an incorrect usage of `\put`. Put is defined to take 3 arguments in a specific delimited form (from `latex.ltx`):

```
\long\gdef\put(#1,#2)#3{%
  \@killglue\raise#2\unitlength
  \hb@xt@\z@{\kern#1\unitlength #3\hss}%
  \ignorespaces}
```

Using `\pd(<x>,<y>,<stuff>)` expands to

```
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\put(<x>,<y>)\expandafter{<stuff>}}
```

where `\put` grabs `<x>` as `#1`, `<y>` as `#2` and `\expandafter` as `#3`. Perhaps the following definition of `\pd` is what you're after:

```
\def\pd(#1,#2,#3){% \pd(<x>,<y>,<stuff>)
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG{\put(#1,#2){#3}}}
```

which will appropriately pass `#3` to `\put`.

Here's a complete minimal example showing the difference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{eso-pic,pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{eso-pic,pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\def\pdA(#1,#2,#3){\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\put(#1,#2)\expandafter{#3}}}
\def\pdB(#1,#2,#3){\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\put(#1,#2){#3}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\put(35,555){\large X}}
\pdA(150,150,{\color{red}Rhubarb and crumble})
\pdB(150,150,{\color{green}Rhubarb and crumble})
\pdB(100,100,{Crumble topping})
\includepdf[pages=1-1]{lipsum50}
\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect thank you. why does the `\putstuff` need to be `\protected`? thanks

Comment: @TahnoonPasha: Some commands should not be expanded until the actual typesetting occurs. In this case, `\color`. See a short discussion on this topic in [Minimal `\protected@edef` example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5693/5764).

Comment: Hi @Werner, having tried the macro, it seems to have a problem with multiple form inputs. So if I use `\pdA(50,50,{Rhubarb and Custard})` and then `\pdA(150,150,{Crumble topping})` then I get "Crumble topping" for both. Do you know what is going wrong here?

Comment: @TahnoonPasha: See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Werner. Bizarre, that was the first thing I tried but it didn't work hence my question. Must have typed it in wrong or something.