# Macro concatenation via expansion multiple times with some tokens protected?

Tags: macros, expansion

In the MWE below, I want to create a `\doPlotCoords` macro from scratch, by appending `\addplot` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\xdef\doPlotCoords{}
\foreach \r in {0,1,...,10}{%
  \xdef\tempCoords{} %
  \foreach \c in {0,1,...,10}{ %
    \xdef\tempCoords{\tempCoords (\r,\c)\space}
  } % end \foreach \c
  % just \xdef concatenating gives "! Undefined control sequence." for \addplot; use \protected@edef
%   \xdef\doPlotCoords{ \doPlotCoords
%   \noexpand\addplot+[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates{ \tempCoords };}
  % with "\protected@xdef", I get "! You can't use a prefix with `the character @'.":
  \makeatletter %
  \protected@xdef\doPlotCoords{ \doPlotCoords
  \protect\addplot+[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates{ \tempCoords };}
  \makeatother
} % end \foreach \r

\begin{document}
\show\doPlotCoords
\end{document}
```

Eventually, I'd like the `\doPlotCoords` macro to contain:

```
\addplot+[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates{ (0,0) (0,1) ... };
\addplot+[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates{ (1,0) (1,1) ... };
...
```

... so I could just use `\doPlotCoords` as a "subroutine" to execute all those `\addplot`s; however, currently it fails with:

```
! You can't use a prefix with `the character @'.
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.26 }
       % end \foreach \r
```

I think the main problem is that: upon the first `\xdef`, `\protect`/`\noexpand` may be obeyed; but when concatenating, the `\doPlotCoords` already contains the `\addplot`, so when the `\xdef` tries to expand `\doPlotCoords`, it also  wants to expand the `\addplot` inside. But I cannot really see what the "You can't use a prefix with `the character @'." should refer to, when using `\protected@xdef` (got that via [Minimal \protected@edef example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/minimal-protectededef-example)).

So how could I build a macro using a `\edef\mymacro{\mymacro something else}` type concatenation, such that the protected tokens inside `\mymacro` are not expanded when the `\edef` runs multiple times on `\mymacro`? (<sub>I kind of think that this "multiple times" might justify calling this approach "recursive macro concatenation"; but I'm not sure, as this isn't a "real" recursion of the function-calling-itself kind...</sub>)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is similar to the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\zz}[1]{%
  \makeatletter%
  \protected@edef\zzz{#1}%
  \makeatother%
}
\begin{document}

abc\zz{zz}

\end{document}
```

You try to be concise in your macro programming, using a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) only when it's necessary. In this case, just around the macro using an `@` symbol - `\protected@edef`. However, by the time you *declare* the definition of `\zz`, the category codes for its replacement text (everything inside the braced group) has already been set. That is, the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair has no effect on correctly interpreting the `@` in `\protected@edef`.

The solution is to use the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair *outside* the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\zz}[1]{%
  \protected@edef\zzz{#1}%
}
\makeatother%
\begin{document}

abc\zz{zz}

\end{document}
```

The same goes for the `\foreach` loops you create. They are in essence also just macros that take arguments in order to delimit the scope. So, once these arguments are read (as a whole), category code changes have no effect on its contents. Place the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair *outside* the *outermost* (lowest) group (`\foreach` in your case in order to use `@`-like macros properly:

```
\makeatletter
\foreach ... {
  ...
  \foreach ... {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed exposition @Werner, great to have this reference.  Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `\makeatletter` inside the argument of another command (for same reason you can not use `\verb` there, but you don't really need `@` commands here anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

 \xdef\doPlotCoords{}
{\let\addplot\relax
\foreach \r in {0,1,...,10}{%
  \xdef\tempCoords{}%
  \foreach \c in {0,1,...,10}{%
    \xdef\tempCoords{\tempCoords (\r,\c)\space}
  }

 \xdef\doPlotCoords{\doPlotCoords
  \addplot+[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates{ \tempCoords };}
}% end \foreach \r
}


\begin{document}
\show\doPlotCoords
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @DavidCarlisle - I remember I tried this example with `\xdef` originally, but I cannot recall what the problem was, but it made me look further, and at that point I found `\protected@xdef` and I used it; good to know it isn't really needed. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau you probably didn't do `\let\addplot\relax`

Answer (score 5):

You may enjoy an `expl3` implementation. The macro `\dosteps` is a wrapper around `\int_step_inline:nnnn`; the syntax is

```
\dostep{<initial>}[<step>]{<final>}{<code>}
```

where the step is optional (default 1). In the `<code>`, the current value is available as `#1`. If a `\dosteps` is called inside `<code>`, for the inner cycle the current value is available as `##1` (and so on, doubling the number of `#`).

The macro `\appendto` appends the second argument to the parameterless macro given as first argument; the `*`-variant does complete expansion. In order to avoid using `\noexpand\addplot`, I defined a `\paddplot` macro that's essentially the same, but protected under expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dosteps}{mO{1}mm}
 {%#1=start, #2=step (default 1), #3=end, #4=code
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendto}{smm}
 {%#1=*, #2=token list, #3=code
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\tl_put_right:Nx}{\tl_put_right:Nn} #2 { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\tempCoords{} % initialize
\newcommand\doPlotCoords{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\paddplot}{}{\addplot}% protected version of \addplot

\dosteps{0}{10}{%
  \renewcommand{\tempCoords}{}% reinitialize
  \dosteps{0}{10}{%
    \appendto\tempCoords{(#1,##1) }% #1 is the outer cycle, ##1 the inner one
  }
  \appendto*\doPlotCoords{%
    \paddplot+[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates { \tempCoords };
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\show\doPlotCoords
\end{document}
```

This is the output on the terminal for the final `\show` command:

```
> \doPlotCoords=macro:
->\addplot +[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates { (0,0) (0,1) 
(0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5) (0,6) (0,7) (0,8) (0,9) (0,10) }; \addplot +[color=blue
,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates { (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5)
 (1,6) (1,7) (1,8) (1,9) (1,10) }; \addplot +[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={b
lue},] coordinates { (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6) (2,7) (2,8) (2,9
) (2,10) }; \addplot +[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates { (3
,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6) (3,7) (3,8) (3,9) (3,10) }; \addplot +[
color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates { (4,0) (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (
4,4) (4,5) (4,6) (4,7) (4,8) (4,9) (4,10) }; \addplot +[color=blue,mark=*,mark 
options={blue},] coordinates { (5,0) (5,1) (5,2) (5,3) (5,4) (5,5) (5,6) (5,7) 
(5,8) (5,9) (5,10) }; \addplot +[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordi
nates { (6,0) (6,1) (6,2) (6,3) (6,4) (6,5) (6,6) (6,7) (6,8) (6,9) (6,10) }; \
addplot +[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates { (7,0) (7,1) (7,
2) (7,3) (7,4) (7,5) (7,6) (7,7) (7,8) (7,9) (7,10) }; \addplot +[color=blue,ma
rk=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates { (8,0) (8,1) (8,2) (8,3) (8,4) (8,5) (8
,6) (8,7) (8,8) (8,9) (8,10) }; \addplot +[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue
},] coordinates { (9,0) (9,1) (9,2) (9,3) (9,4) (9,5) (9,6) (9,7) (9,8) (9,9) (
9,10) }; \addplot +[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={blue},] coordinates { (10,0
) (10,1) (10,2) (10,3) (10,4) (10,5) (10,6) (10,7) (10,8) (10,9) (10,10) }; .
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @egreg - stuff like this will make me want study Latex 3 soon `:)` Cheers!