# Why does \edef produce an error if its arguments is a command that takes an argument?

Tags: macros

If I have the following piece of code, everything compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\newcommand{\mycmd}{
  \edef\tmpcmd{test} % No commands with arguments
  \tmpcmd
}

\begin{document}
\mycmd
\end{document}
```

But if it looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\newcommand{\mycmd}{
  \edef\tmpcmd{\textit{test}} % Has a command with argument
  \tmpcmd
}

\begin{document}
\mycmd
\end{document}
```

Then I get a weird error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.9 \mycmd
```

Why is this?

Comment: You can't even do `\edef\tmpcmd{\textit{test}}` outside of `\mycmd`, much less inside a macro.  Some macros are just not expandable.

Comment: See _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/minimal-protectededef-example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue isn't that the macro has an argument, but whether the argument is expandable.  For example, this slight alteration of your MWE works fine, since `\foo` is expandable:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\newcommand{\mycmd}{%
  \edef\tmpcmd{\foo{test}}% Has a command with argument
  \tmpcmd
}
\newcommand\foo[1]{foo:#1:bar}
\begin{document}
\mycmd
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem with the OP's MWE is that `\textit` is not fully expandable.

The `\protected@edef` macro can get one through many of these situations, and the links that Joseph mentions in his comment to the OP, which I repeat here for convenience, explain in intricate detail all the reasons why.

[Minimal \protected@edef example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/minimal-protectededef-example)

[What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

```
\documentclass{article}  
\makeatletter  
\newcommand{\mycmd}{%
  \protected@edef\tmpcmd{\textit{test}}% Has a command with argument
  \tmpcmd
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mycmd
\end{document}
```

[image]

In addition to searching this site for "expandable", looking into the concepts of "fragile" and "robust" would also be instructive, as Gustavo notes.

Comment: Well, the reason why this works is that `\textit` is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

`\protected@edef` (see Steven’s answer), however, won’t inihibit the expansion of commands not declared as robust, unless you explicitly `\protect` them inside the replacement text.  The following, trivial alternative

```
\documentclass{article}  
\newcommand*{\mycmd}{%
  \edef\tmpcmd{\noexpand\textit{test}}%
  \tmpcmd
}

\begin{document}
\mycmd
\end{document}
```

is more general, probably neater, and has the additional advantage of sparing an infinitesimal amount of memory.

Comment: Now I see where you were going with your comment.  Nice. +1

Comment: I beg to disagree: `\protected@edef` is the way to go.

Comment: @egreg: Would you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: Look at the duplicate question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252183/edef-together-with-microtype-generates-an-error and tell how you'd use `\noexpand`.

Comment: I’m afraid I can’t get at what you mean: referring to the example you mention, what’s wrong with `\keyword[na\noexpand\"ive]`?  But I cannot initiate a discussion in the comments: are you willing to teach me something about this issue on chat?  (If I can abuse your time, of course! :-)