# Why textbf is not working in macro

Tags: macros

Here is my code:

```
\newcommand{\testtest}[1]{%%
  \stepcounter{aebir@prob@cnt}%%
  \edef\aebir@tmp{#1}}
 
\testtest{$\frac{1}{2}$}
\aebir@tmp{}
```

This prints 1/2 which is fine. But if I try to write something like

```
\newcommand{\testtest}[1]{%%
  \stepcounter{aebir@prob@cnt}%%
  \edef\aebir@tmp{#1}}
 
\testtest{\textbf{A}}
\aebir@tmp{}
```

this not printing bold letter A. This just fails to run. This is a part of my longer code but I need to solve this problem first.

Probably the problem is due to that {#1} thing. Because

```
\def\aeiki@tmp{\textbf{A}}
\aeiki@tmp{}
```

This is working perfectly.

Thanks!

---

Sorry for the bad explanation. Here is my full code, this is something that I need to use for creating an answer key.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{aebir@prob@cnt}
\let\aebir@answer@key\relax

\newcommand\dogrucevapbir[1]{%%
  \stepcounter{aebir@prob@cnt}%%
  \edef\aebir@tmp{\theaebir@prob@cnt/#1}%%
  \ifx\relax\aebir@answer@key
    \edef\aebir@answer@key{\aebir@tmp}%%
  \else
    \edef\aebir@answer@key{\aebir@answer@key,\aebir@tmp}%%
  \fi
  }

Question 1: Correct answer is A.
\dogrucevapbir{A}

Question 2: Correct answer is B.
\dogrucevapbir{B}

Question 3: Correct answer is C.
\dogrucevapbir{C}

Here is the answer key:

\aebir@answer@key{}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: This is result that I get:]

But If I try something like \dogrucevapbir{\textbf{A}} or \dogrucevapbir{\dfrac{1}{2}}, I'm getting error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be easier to answer the question if your example of code was already compilable. Also, maybe you could clarify why you want to use `\edef` here. If I complete your code to make it compilable and replace `\edef` with `\newcommand`, it compiles fine.

Comment: If you understand everything in [macros - Minimal \protected@edef example - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/minimal-protectededef-example?noredirect=1&lq=1), you'll be able to diagnose your problem. (nevertheless you have not shown what you *actually* want here, so a perfectly-valid workaround is to replace `\edef` with `\newcommand`.

Comment: Please provide your `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Don't use \edef on arbitrary text.

Comment: You should separate the formatting and the name of the key. The system will not know what `\theaebir@prob@cnt/\textbf{A}` is in the first place.

Comment: The problem is not just formatting. Sometimes I need to write something like \dfrac{1}{2} into it or maybe \\ for long answers.

Comment: It **is** the problem, don't use exotic material as data keys. That will just come back to bite you. Then add and extra variable to keep this in under the same simple key.

Answer (score 9):

You can not use `\edef` on arbitrary latex input. You give no indication what you want the command to do, but it looks like expansion is not needed here, so you can use `\def`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{aebir@prob@cnt}
\newcommand{\testtest}[1]{%%
  \stepcounter{aebir@prob@cnt}%%
  \def\aebir@tmp{#1}}
 
\testtest{$\frac{1}{2}$}
\aebir@tmp{}

\testtest{\textbf{A}}
\aebir@tmp{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend using old style commands. You can use `\edef` but you have to know what do you want to expand and what not.

```
\newcount\probcnt
\def\answerkey{}

\def\dogrucevapbir#1{%
  \global\advance\probcnt by1
  \xdef\answerkey{\ifnum\probcnt=1 1\else
     \unexpanded\expandafter{\answerkey}, \the\probcnt\fi
     /\unexpanded{#1}}%
}

Question 1: Correct answer is A.
\dogrucevapbir{A}

Question 2: Correct answer is B.
\dogrucevapbir{B}

Question 3: Correct answer is C.
\dogrucevapbir{C}

Here is the answer key:

\answerkey
```

Comment: This is a straight copy of my answer, were it not for the fact that the list you build is “static”,  cannot be used for other purposes without defining an ad hoc parser and it's built with very awkward looking commands.

Comment: This is not copy of egreg's answer. I don't use `\int_gincr:N`, `\exp_not:n` etc. because I don't understand this. I use only well known TeX primitives `\xdef`, `\the` etc. My answer is usable in TeX environments where Expl3 language isn't present.

Comment: I'd say that the very awkward looking commands are in egreg's answer.  This is using only well known commands as wipet says.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using new style commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g_ertan_answer_count_int
\clist_new:N \g_ertan_answer_keys_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\dogrucevapbir}{m}
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_ertan_answer_count_int
  \clist_gput_right:Nx \g_ertan_answer_keys_clist
   {
    \int_to_arabic:n { \g_ertan_answer_count_int } / \exp_not:n {#1} 
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printanswerkeys}{}
 {
  \clist_use:Nn \g_ertan_answer_keys_clist { ,~ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Question 1: Correct answer is A.
\dogrucevapbir{A}

Question 2: Correct answer is B.
\dogrucevapbir{$\frac{1}{2}$}

Question 3: Correct answer is C.
\dogrucevapbir{\textbf{C}}

Here is the answer key:

\printanswerkeys

\end{document}
```

[image]